# Display only the previous month's name in dropdown list (according to financial year)

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the dropdown list the 1st month should start from April and end with March.
If current month is May it should only display April, like wise if the current month is March it should list (April to Feb) dynamically.

If the current month is April it should not display anything.

```
var previousMonth = DateTime.Now.Month == 1 ? 1 : DateTime.Now.Month - 1 ;
var months = Enumerable.Range(1, previousMonth).Select(i => new { I = i, M = 
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i) });
DropDownList3.DataSource = months;
DropDownList3.DataTextField = "M";
DropDownList3.DataValueField = "I";
DropDownList3.DataBind();
```

Above is my code which is working, but its displaying from jan to dec.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of what you tried to do to solve this issue.

Comment: as you are new contributor, please post your code and whats not working.

Comment: @Gauravsa i have edited my question, please check the code.

Comment: @CoolBots i have updated the question with code please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (I think):

```
const int startMonth = 4;
var previousMonth = ((DateTime.Now.Month - 2) % 12) + 1;
var months = Enumerable.Range(startMonth - 1, (previousMonth - startMonth + 13) % 12).Select(i => new
    {
        I = (i % 12) + 1, M = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName((i % 12) + 1)
    });

DropDownList3.DataSource = months;
DropDownList3.DataTextField = "M";
DropDownList3.DataValueField = "I";
DropDownList3.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
        List<string> months = new List<string>
        {
            "March",
            "February",
            "January",
            "December",
            "November",
            "October",
            "September",
            "August",
            "July",
            "June",
            "May",
            "April",
            ""
        };

        var previousMonth = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month);
        var newMonths = months.Skip(months.IndexOf(previousMonth)+1).Reverse().ToArray();

        DropDownList2.DataSource = newMonths;
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "M";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "I";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
```